# How does this Scala function work?

Tags: scala

```
def flatMap[A,B](f: Rand[A])(g: A => Rand[B]): Rand[B] =rng => {
    val (a, r1) = f(rng)
    g(a)(r1) 
}
```

I am confused by `g(a)(r1)` because g is supposed to take only one argument, so why r1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know the `Rand[A]` structure, so this is partially guessing. What you are returning in this function is a `Rand[B]` and when you implement the function you start of with defining an argument `rng` of an anonymous function. This tells me that `Rand` is probably some kind of function itself.

In the second line (`val (a, r1) = f(rng)`) you apply the value `rng` to the instance `f: Rand[A]`. In the resulting tuple, `a` has type `A`.

Note with this that `f(rng)` is equal to explicitly calling `apply`: `f.apply(rng)`.

You can use the value `a` to get a `Rand[B]` by applying this value to the function `g`. So, `val rb: Rand[B] = g(a)` (or `g.apply(a)`).

Now, you don't want to return an instance of `Rand[B]` in this anonymous function! Instead you need to apply the previous result `r1` to this instance `rb`. So, you get `rb(r1)` or `rb.apply(r1)`. Substituting `rb` with `g(a)` or `g.apply(a)` gives you `g(a)(r1)` or `g.apply(a).apply(r1)`.

To summarize, as you said, `g` is supposed to only take one argument, which results in an instance of `Rand[B]`, but that is not the expected return type here. You need to apply the result of the previous computation to this new computation to get the expected result.